# Disable filters which MediaElement uses

Tags: wpf, directshow, mediaelement, directshow.net

**Is it possible to disable filters which WPF's MediaElement is allowed to use?**

I am disabling specific filters through [IAMPluginControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319756%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using DirectShow.NET.

```
IAMPluginControl pluginControl
    = new DirectShowPluginControl() as IAMPluginControl;
if ( pluginControl == null )
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "Can't access DirectShow plugin filter control." );
}

bool disabled = pluginControl.SetDisabled(_directVobSub, true) == 0;
disabled &= pluginControl.SetDisabled(_directVobSubAutoloading, true) == 0;
disabled &= pluginControl.SetDisabled(_lavSplitter, true) == 0;

InitializeComponent();
```

I do this in the constructor of a video control, prior to calling `InitializeComponent()`. `pluginControl` indicates that the filters are in fact disabled, but this doesn't seem to affect to graph of `MediaElement`.

An important note is I can't see the graph explicitly. I am only guessing the graph is still using DirectVobSub as this should give a noticeable different visible result.

Comment: This does seem to have an effect after all! It seems I have to do some extra setup in order to achieve the filter graph I am hoping to create.

Comment: Why won't you check the graph topology exactly?

Comment: @RomanR: I tried using your Spy tool, but I didn't get it to work yet. Still have to check the log file to see whether both dll's registered correctly. Right now I just used graphedit with intelligent connect to render the desired file. By disabling the filters I'm trying to disable through `IAMPluginControl` in the registry I can see the different graphs being formed in graphedit.

Comment: BTW I understand your worries about `DirectVobSub` - it puts itself on top of things in order to interfere into graphs. I see you are trying to disable it, I thought you might want to try to disable it in another way to see if it fixes your problems? Note this is more a guess as I am not sure what exactly problems you are trying to solve by blacklisting filters.

Comment: Also just to make sure - `IAMPluginControl` is only available in Windows 7+.

Comment: @RomanR.: You got it right, `DirectVobSub` is indeed messing with my graph, which is why I want to disable it. Enabling `DirectVobSub` actually only had the side effect of intelligent connect preferring the LAV splitter over the AVI splitter. It's the AVI splitter which allowed the behavior I desired. (possibility to change video rate dynamically without delay) I'll post a more extensive description in an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RomanR.: P.s., got your [spy tool](http://alax.info/blog/777) to work. I'm guessing it was a x86 vs x64 issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible starting from Windows 7.

I wasn't seeing any difference since still a different graph than expected was being created. DirectVobSub (auto-loading) persisted in showing up in the graph, but disabling any other filters works.

I didn't find any other way than to disable DirectVobSub through the registry.

P.s.: The 'effect' I was looking for is the possibility to dynamically change the playback rate of the video without visible delays after rate changes. Hooking DirectVobSub in the graph seems to prevent this from being possible.

---

As a reference for the older comments:

Before I thought that by setting the AVI Splitter as the preferred AVI filter, everything worked as expected, and that disabling DirectVobSub wasn't required. The actual reason it seemed to work at that point was since I was building x64 instead of x86, and DirectVobSub didn't intervene for this reason.

Comment: Before Windows 7, you could insist on `AVI Splitter` in a few ways: (1) build graph manually and add the filter explicitly (2) blacklist `LAV Splitter` via `IAMGraphBuilderCallback`, (3) register fake COM class factory under `LAV Splitter` CLSID, (4) detect auto-added `LAV Splitter` and replace it in code with `AVI Splitter`. Some of the options might be a paint to implement if you are not using DirectShow directly and details are covered by third party layers on top of DirectShow.

Comment: @RomanR.: (1) As far as I know it's impossible to create a custom graph for `MediaElement`. This is why I was resorting to `IAMPluginControl`. (2) Strangely enough, blacklisting `LAV splitter` through `IAMPluginControl` wasn't sufficient, I guess some other splitter took its place. (3) Thanks, I might check that out. (3 & 4) Would this work without access to the graph?

Comment: If you know that `LAV Splitter` is something - when installed - which might be a paint for your application, and you cannot (don't want for a reason) disable it through `IAMGraphBuilderCallback`, then #3 is simple and powerful enough. You create a dummy COM class with perhaps IClassFactory only, and register it with `CoRegisterClasObject`. Since there, all attempts to instantiate this filter will be routed - within your app - to your class and your would just return failure.